# Django include template, overwrite 'self' variable?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I've been tasked to fix a template structure in a Django app.  I am not very familiar with Django as I deal mostly with front end projects built in React.

The Django app is using Wagtail as a backend CMS.  I am looping through it's pages, and including a template block and trying to pass variables with the `with` statement on the `include`.  I can successfully pass variables to the template block, but I need to overwrite the 'self' variable as the template block is looking for `self.something`.

Here is what my template looks like.

```
{% load static wagtailimages_tags wagtailcore_tags %}

<div class="c-card {% if self.variant %}c-card--{{ self.variant }}{% endif %}">
    {% if self.image %}
        {% image self.image original class="c-card__image" loading="lazy" %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if self.title %}
        <h3 class="c-card__title">{{ self.title }}</h3>
    {% endif %}

    {% if self.text %}
        <p class="c-card__content">{{ self.text }}</p>
    {% endif %}

    {% if self.button.title and self.button.url %}
        {% include './button_block.html' with button=self.button %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

and then there is the loop and include snippet...

```
{% for chapter_menu in page.chapters %}
    <div class="medium-6 large-4 columns">
        {{ chapter_menu.value.title }}
        {% include './blocks/card_block.html' with self=chapter_menu.value %}
    </div>
{%  endfor %}
```

Doing this `self=chapter_menu.value` results in a TypeError, which is expected as I am defining `self` twice. `push() got multiple values for argument 'self'`

How can I go about doing this?  Any docs I can read besides the basic django templating docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with

Comment: "Doing this self=chapter_menu.value results in a TypeError", what are you saying exactly? The above `include ... with ...` tag results in a TypeError? Or where are you "doing self=chapter_menu.value"?

Answer (score 1):

add the `only` attribute to include.... Did not find this in any documentation...

`{% include './blocks/card_block.html' with self=chapter_menu.value only %}`

Comment: `only` is [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include). We're talking about the `include` tag, not the `with` tag (`with` here is just an option).